# Darwin kernel disk device to pass disk arbitration

Tags: kernel, device, disk, darwin, zfs

So I ported latest ZFS to OSX (`github/osx.zfs`), then added ZVOL as it is something I wanted. Now the pure BSD kernel side of things do appear to work, but I am having issues with Apple specific integration. I'm just missing a piece of the puzzle.

I create the new virtual disks (ZVOLs) similar to other Darwin kernel example, by defining `bdevsw` and `cdevsw` and calling `bdevsw_add` and `cdevsw_add_with_bdev`. As can be seen here: [create /dev/zfs](https://github.com/zfs-osx/zfs/blob/zvol/module/zfs/zfs_ioctl.c#L5280), which is the main ZFS node and handles all specific ioctl. Then the ZVOL virtual disk nodes are created here [create /dev/disk_POOL_name](https://github.com/zfs-osx/zfs/blob/zvol/module/zfs/zvol.c#L520)

(I have tried naming the dev nodes as `disk3` and `rdisk3` which did not make any difference).

I handle most ioctl that I have received using `newfs_msdos` `newfs_hfs` `newfs_udf`, here [handle ioctl](https://github.com/zfs-osx/zfs/blob/zvol/module/zfs/zvol.c#L2183)

So, basically, it creates the BSD /dev/ entries, I can newfs my virtual disk, I can mount it, use it. From Unix POV, it appears to work as a disk.

But not in OSX. It does not show in "diskutil list", nor in the GUI Disk Utility. Clearly I need to do something else in the kernel to make it be considered.
Or, is it something I should do in userland?

```
# ./zpool.sh create -f BOOM ~/pool-image.bin 
# ./cmd.sh zfs create -V 50M -o volblocksize=4096 BOOM/vol
# ls -l /dev/*disk*
brw-r-----  1 root      operator    1,   3 Apr  9 01:48 disk0s2
brw-r-----  1 root      operator    1,   2 Apr  9 01:48 disk0s1
brw-r-----  1 root      operator    1,   0 Apr  9 01:48 disk0
crw-r-----  1 root      operator    1,   0 Apr  9 01:48 rdisk0
crw-------  1 root      operator    33,   1 May 27 08:53 rdisk_BOOM_vol
brw-------  1 root      operator    3,   1 May 27 08:53 disk_BOOM_vol
# newfs_msdos  /dev/rdisk_BOOM_vol
/dev/rdisk_BOOM_vol: 12781 sectors in 12781 FAT16 clusters (4096 bytes/cluster)
bps=4096 spc=1 res=1 nft=2 rde=512 sec=12800 mid=0xf0 spf=7 spt=32 hds=16 hid=0 drv=0x00
# mkdir /Volumes/pc
# mount_msdos /dev/disk_BOOM_vol /Volumes/pc
# df -h
/dev/disk_BOOM_vol   102248    560  101688     1%     512   0  100%   /Volumes/pc
# mkdir /Volumes/pc/HELLO
# ls -l /Volumes/pc
drwxrwxrwx  1 _unknown  _unknown  4096 May 27 08:53 HELLO
# diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *21.5 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Dev                     21.1 GB    disk0s2
# diskutil list /dev/rdisk_BOOM_vol
Could not find whole disk for disk: /dev/rdisk_BOOM_vol
```

I have yet to handle anything to do with partitions, but I feel the raw disk should at least show in Disk Utility so that I can attempt to partition it.

Comment: kudos for up'ing the ZFS/MacOSX port.

Comment: If anyone would like to discuss or have other suggestions, the ticket for this issue is at [github](https://github.com/zfs-osx/zfs/issues/29)

Comment: Ok, I got around to replacing it with IOKit and C++, based on the example in Halvorsen's kernel book, and it 'just works'. Clearly IOKit is what Apple wants you to use, and BSD nodes are mostly left in for non-block devices.